# How to use the numericality validation with an integer column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Given an integer column how do I prevent a alphanumeric being stored as zero?

I tried using the `numericality` validator but it seems that the value is checked post typecast (using `to_i`) so a string like `'dd1'` is typecast to `0` and thus passes the validation.

```
validates :portfolio_number, numericality: { only_integer: true, allow_nil: true }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own validation which checks the value for typecasting:

```
validate :portfolio_number_is_numeric

private

def portfolio_number_is_numeric
  return unless value.present?
  errors.add(:portfolio_number, 'must be numeric') unless read_attribute_before_type_cast(:portfolio_number).match?(/\A[0-9]*\z/)
end
```

This could potentially be extracted in to a validator object for reusability.